# How to combine below two `ifs` formulas in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

How to combine below two `ifs` formulas in excel?

```
=IF(AND( Sheet1!BC2<>"", Sheet1!CI2<>"",Sheet1!CA2=""),IF(Sheet1!CI2="","",Sheet1!CI2),IF(Sheet1!CA2="","",Sheet1!CA2)


=IF(AND( Sheet1!BC2="B",Sheet1!CI2<>""),IF(Sheet1!CI2="","",Sheet1!CI2),IF(Sheet1!CA2="","",Sheet1!CA2)
```

Both formulas are working correct individually .

Actually its a huge excel sheet in first cycle i did filtering and alter the data with `Sheet1!BC2<>"",Sheet1!CI2<>"",Sheet1!CA2=""` . In next phase I have to filter and to fill the blank data with this condition `Sheet1!BC2="B",Sheet1!CI2<>""` . Though they work perfectly alone but how to write it in combination .

Comment: Your formula is incorrect. Look at the first formula: If `AND( Sheet1!BC2<>"", Sheet1!CI2<>"",Sheet1!CA2="")` is true, then `Sheet1!CI2<>""` is true. So, why did you check again with second `IF` function? `IF(Sheet1!CI2="","",Sheet1!CI2)` ? The second IF statement runs only if `Sheet1!CI2<>""` is true

Comment: You should simplify your code

Comment: Actually its a huge excel sheet in first cycle i did filtering and alter the data with `Sheet1!BC2<>"",Sheet1!CI2<>"",Sheet1!CA2=""` .In next phase I have to filter and to fill the blank data with this condition `Sheet1!BC2="B",Sheet1!CI2<>"" ` . Though they work perfectly alone but how to write it in combination .

Comment: Why did you check `Sheet1!CI2<>""` twice?

Comment: I am not using it twice but they are mentioned in two different formulas. This formula is for column `CA` It should satisfy both formulas

Comment: If you put this formula into Column `CA`, Excel will raise a cyclic error.

Comment: Actually its partially working . Its overwriting all the values of column CI into CA. Do you suggest to write it in another way ?

Comment: see my edited answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EDITED] Try this:

```
=IF(AND( Sheet1!BC2<>"", Sheet1!CI2<>"",Sheet1!CA2=""),IF(Sheet1!BC2="B",Sheet1!CI2,Sheet1!CA2),IF(Sheet1!CA2="","",Sheet1!CA2))
```

Comment: Thanks . But answer is same as @Jordan

Answer (score 0):

As your resulting `TRUE` and `FALSE` `IF` statements are the same I'm assuming you just want to use something like the `OR` statement with your `AND`:

```
=IF(OR(AND(Sheet1!BC2<>"",Sheet1!CI2<>"",Sheet1!CA2=""),AND(Sheet1!BC2="B",Sheet1!CI2<>"")),IF(Sheet1!CI2="","",Sheet1!CI2),IF(Sheet1!CA2="","",Sheet1!CA2))
```

Comment: The issue with yoru combination is that its copying the CI into CA even if CI  has values. I want if CA is blank then it should copy the values from CI otherwise let the cell value of CA remain same.

Comment: I tried to make it more simple, but the core functionality is same. Pleas help. I have changed the question I previous.

Comment: Your fomula is working for the terms CA is blank so its copying it from CI. But it also overwrites the vlaues of CA with CI present values

Comment: So let me get this right. The value needs to be `CA2` unless `CA2` is blank in which case the `IF` statement should return the value of `CI2`? What about the `Sheet1!BC="B"` criteria? Should that take the highest priority over all other criteria?

Comment: Actually its a huge excel sheet in first cycle i did filtering and alter the data with `Sheet1!BC2<>"",Sheet1!CI2<>"",Sheet1!CA2=""` .In next phase I have to filter and to fill the blank data with this condition `Sheet1!BC2="B",Sheet1!CI2<>"" ` . Though they work perfectly alone but how to write it in combination .